# Doctrine 2 ResultSetMapping Many-To-Many example

Tags: php, sql, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to use ResultSetMappingBuilder to get data from Native query.

```
$sql = "SELECT e.start_date FROM se_events e 
            LEFT JOIN se_event_tags tg ON e.id = tg.event_id 
            LEFT JOIN se_event_type t ON tg.event_type_id = t.id
            WHERE t.id = :id";
```

I have no idea how to build ResultSetMappingBuilder.

```
public function createResultSetMapping() {
    $rsm = new \Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMappingBuilder($this->getEntityManager());
    $rsm->addRootEntityFromClassMetadata('Event', 'e');
    return $rsm;
}
```

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've used row SQL:

```
$sql = "SELECT e.start_date FROM se_events e 
LEFT JOIN se_event_tags tg ON e.id = tg.event_id 
LEFT JOIN se_event_type t ON tg.event_type_id = t.id
WHERE t.id = $id";
$stmt = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
return $stmt->fetchAll();
```